# Jest encountered an unexpected token and doesn't recongnise ES6 and JSX

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Jest doesn't recognize JSX and ES6. I am also using webpack version 3. I also recently updated deprecated babel packages to the newest versions. [image]

[![enter image description here]

jest.config.js:

```
    module.exports = {
        verbose: true,
        transform: {
            "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
            },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
                "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@babel).+\\.js$"
              ],
    }
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 "presets": [ "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
 "plugins": [
    [   
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      },
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    ]
  ]
}
```

My test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import AccessSeeker from './AccessSeeker';
// import Home from './Home'
// import BankStatementPage from './BankStatementPage';

test('renders', () => {
    render(<AccessSeeker/>)
})
```

Comment: Can you take the entire screenshot to see where the error pointed to?

Comment: added, have a look above please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is jest doesn't resolve your css files which is usually ignored during test. You can achieve that by mocking it as adding following configuration:

```json
moduleNameMapper: {
  "^.+.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub"
}

// Keep in mind to install `npm i -D jest-transform-stub` before using
```

Comment: Fixed !!!! Thank you my friend !!! You saved my life